# Can one candy bar per day be part of a healthy diet?

Tags: nutrition, diet

Are there any ill effects from eating one normally size candy bar per day over a long period of time, as part of an otherwise well-balanced diet for an active adult?

For example, a Twix bar with:

- 250 calories
- 12 g total fat
- 7 g saturated fat
- 24 g sugar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twix is part of an *otherwise* healthy diet.

According to the American Heart Association the limit is [36 grams of sugar](http://www.heart.org/HEARTORG/HealthyLiving/HealthyEating/Nutrition/Sugar-101_UCM_306024_Article.jsp#.WIzyC1MrJaQ).  That is 2/3 of the recommended maximum in one little bar.

That one little bar is 35% of the recommended saturated fat for the day.

You would need an otherwise perfect diet to balance out. People with an otherwise perfect diet just don't have a craving for a Twix.  I seriously doubt what you are characterizing as well-balanced diet is a perfect diet other than the Twix.

If you have a craving for something sweet then a 1-2 sweet fruits is part of a healthy diet.

Answer (score 1):

It's harmful, because what passes for the rest of the so-called "well-balanced diet" isn't actually all that healthy either, it will also contain a fair amount of sugar, and saturated fats and also unsaturated fats which are healthier than saturated fats but not healthy in an absolute sense. So, what passes for a healthy, well-balanced diet is a diet that isn't too bad, but certainly not the most healthy diet you can imagine. This should be considered to be a compromise between what is extremely healthy and what the general public can be convinced to stick to.

If you then further compromise on this by getting about 10% more of your calories from sugars and fats, of which a large fraction will be saturated fats, you're going to do yet more damage to your body. To get to a healthy diet, you must get rid of almost all the salt, sugar and fats in the diet, even so-called "healthy oils" like olive oil as [Dr. Klaper points out here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OGGQxJLuVjg).

Comment: I think needs needs a more reliable source than a youtube video before it could be considered.